# How to push POST response to array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, http-post

My API works and the structure in the response is below.

[image]

There is one client and client has multiple headers and each header has one Name and URL and so on.

```
THeader1 

 - TReports 
       - Name
       - URL

THeader 2

  -TReports

       -Name
       - URL
```

But I want to push it to be array object where I can use it like below:

```
myVizes = new Array(
                {
                    'name' : 'Test1',
                    'url'  : 'https://test/views/test/Alert?',

                    'hash' : 'test'
                },
                {
                    'name' : 'Test2',
                    'url'  : 'https://blahblah/views/blah/Alert?',

                    'hash' : 'Test2'
                },
                {
                    'name' : 'Test2e',
                    'url'  : 'https://test/views/test?',

                    'hash' : 'Test'
                }

            );
```

However, my jSon

```
getURLS: function (ID)

    {

        var data = {};
        if (typeof (_config.clientID) != 'undefined') {
            data.clientID = _config.clientID;
        }
        var outputdata = '';
        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: _config.GetHeadersByClientAPI,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({TReports:data}),

            success: function (data)
            {
                alert("it works!"+data)
            },

            error: function (xhr, status, error)
            {

                alert("did not work!")
            }



        });


    }
```

My data returns emjpty object. Any thoughts?

Comment: so does it hit the `success` callback and say `it works! {}` (empty object)?

Comment: yes, it hits but it is empty objects